# Discussion: what should we do about the increasing number of questions?

Tags: discussion

Let's try this again.

For some reason I am not allowed to directly share this data (even though I think it is all accessible via [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/)), but let me tell you roughly how the number of questions per day has evolved over the past year.

- One year ago: ~200 questions / day.
- August (summer vacation): ~130 questions / day.
- October: ~200 questions / day.
- November (close to the end of fall semester): ~300 questions / day.
- January (winter vacation): ~170 questions / day.
- February: ~300 questions / day.
- Now (close to the end of spring semester): ~420 questions / day.

(And two years ago? ~70 questions / day.)

In total, about 130,000 questions have been asked on math.SE since its birth. Compare this to the two biggest SE sites after StackOverflow itself: 150,000 questions on ServerFault and 170,000 questions on SuperUser. Both of these sites launched in 2009, so they're both about a **year older** than math.SE.

Overall, it's clear that math.SE is experiencing a much bigger load of questions than it used to. Moreover, in my experience, the average quality of questions has gone down substantially as well.

> What should we do about this?

I will post my suggestion in the answers.

Comment: Should be do anything about this?!

Comment: I think what you meant to ask is «how do we make sure the questions we get get better?» raather than what do we do about getting more and more questions. That's what the answers are about, at least. You would probably not have posted this if we had doubled the number of great questions per day :-)

Comment: What is the issue if we have more questions? If we want to increase the quality of questions (or) decrease the homework questions, we may want to consider a tag based reputation points awarding system. One of the reasons why homework questions and poorly posted questions get more attention is because these are low-hanging fruits to get reputation points. This will hopefully discourage users from answering or posting homework questions.

Comment: @Mariano: Choosing to do nothing should be justified just like any other choice.

Comment: The usual approach for stackexchange sites with high volume on a subject is to split off a new stackexchange site, right? So my modest proposal is to make mathhomeworkanswers.stackexchange.com, and make all math questions in the form of homework help off topic at MSE.

Comment: @Hurkyl, why not undelete the answer, identical to the comment and posted a minute earlier, so that the proposal can gather votes in both directions?  Other than the name of the site, I for one would support it.  I don't wish to spam or take credit for the modest proposal by reposting the suggestion myself as an answer.

Comment: @zyx: Because I meant it satirically. If you mean it seriously, then by all means repost it yourself.

Comment: The formulation of the problem, including the presumption that it is a problem ("what do to about ..."), should also be justified.  Evidently there is a  difference between "let's ban homework!" and the title of this thread.  I consider it a huge improvement, and would have even if I were a homework-hater or an enemy of cut-and-paste questions, because it makes fewer assumptions and allows for more potential solutions. (@Hurkyl )

Comment: @zyx: I don't care about the downvotes. I simply don't think it's appropriate as an answer, since I meant it purely rhetorically to demonstrate the absurdity of a site explicitly devoted to supplying answers for peoples' homework problems, and thus to cast doubt on having that service at MSE. And I have little interest in championing it should people take it seriously. I don't think I would *oppose* the suggestion made seriously, although I tentatively dislike it: while getting rid of the cphq from mse would be good, it would mean losing the useful homework questions too.

Comment: ... and it wouldn't fix the problem of separating the wheat from the chaff for those people (such as myself) who like answering the useful homework questions.

Comment: MSE is not devoted to supplying answers to any particular type of question, and does not acquire such devotion by answering CPHQ.  Nobody is forced to answer anything they don't like, and with a couple of extra tags, essentially nobody (except one retagger per question, or so) has to read anything that is CPQ, CPHQ, or CPwhateverelse if they don't want to.  Talk of on-demand answer services and closing policies is aimed at preventing *answerers* from being able to make their own decisions in case they want the ability to look at those questions and sometimes answer them.  (@Hurkyl )

Comment: @zyx: Talk of on-demand answer services is aimed at trying to prevent MSE from continuing down the road to being an on-demand answer service.

Comment: Yes, but the specific proposals the talkers make always seem to revolve around controlling the answerers in the manner I stated.  And emotionally loaded or rhetorical language like *cheating*, *questionable* and *answer service* always seem to be pressed into service when the proposals are under discussion.  @Hurkyl

Comment: @zyx: ... and jihad and crusade and thought police and...

Comment: @Hurkyl 's comment is rather misleading. "Jihad" and "thought police" were used to describe *user on user attacks*, in the second case with specific description of characteristics that made the attacks 1984-ish (in the first, it is obvious and in any cased visible through results like involuntary thread deletion).  I never used the word "crusade" but was a recipient of that attack.  Hurkyl did not object at the time, but it seems to become an issue after he was described with that word the other day.

Comment: Whereas the emotionalized descriptions like cheating (bad!), questionable activity (BAD!!), and unethical (worse!!!), were used to prejudice the discussion of the actual MSE practices and policies being considered.  That's apart from the sliming of one or more users making opposing arguments as being ethically alien, morally sketchy, dishonest (the last expressed with a stack of $2n$ iterated negations for plausible deniability).

Comment: At any rate, there does not seem to be any disagreement that the endpoint of all these "answer service" type of arguments is restricting the answerers.  There are ways of filtering the questions as well or better without a need for any restrictions, as several people have suggested, but untroubled CPQ-free reading of MSE seems not to be enough for those who don't like the cut-paste questions.  One has to control the questioners and stop the answerers.  If there is a way for you to rarely see the CPQ questions, and everyone else can use the site freely, how is that not a solution?

Comment: @zyx You may not understand this as an anonymous user, but some of us post under our real names. When one googles our names, MSE comes up and the state of MSE will invariably reflect on us. I don't want to be associated with "that free homework answering service".

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, there is a professor and high-reputation user here whose profile states that he wants nothing to do with homework-cheating (or however he characterized it) questions and doesn't answer them.  Nevertheless he is active on MSE and the meta.  Why is that not enough?

Comment: @zyx I know neither whom you are taling about nor what your questions is supposed to mean. What is enough for what purpose and for whom?

Comment: My question was why it is not enough, to prevent the problem you said might arise, to do what this user does in his profile, and let others use the site freely : http://math.stackexchange.com/users/139/douglas-s-stones .  @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: @zyx I'm not sure that everyone looks that closely at profile texts. But the suggestion is good. I think I might steal Douglas's idea.

Comment: Experimenting with Google searches, it looks like for every named academic user, a personal web page is the top ranked hit if one exists, then MathOverflow user page 1-2 hits below that, and MSE user page 1-2 hits below MO.  Because all SE and MO activity links to the user page, that will usually be the top search hit within each site, so there is considerable control over how you present yourself to web searchers.  (@MichaelGreinecker ) .  For so many MSE activities, anything that seems positive can also be seen as negative. Anonymity may be the only way to escape all judgements.

Answer (score 43):

I have several concerns about the increasing load of questions on math.SE. The two primary ones are probably the following:

- I am concerned that I see many low-quality questions that look like homework. I don't want math.SE to acquire a reputation for being a place where it's easy to get homework answers. There are enough places like that on the internet already.
- I am concerned that the decreasing quality of questions will eventually drive away the users who answer questions. I would personally have already stopped using math.SE if I hadn't started aggressively filtering tags (e.g. the [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) tag).

I think both of these concerns would be addressed by **raising our quality standards** for asking questions, as suggested by Eric Naslund [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9182/232). His proposal:

> Low quality questions which show no effort should be downvoted and closed outright. Comments should be added welcoming new users and explaining how to ask the question in a way that is suitable for Math Stack Exchange, and how to ask it in such a way that it is not closed in the future. No emphasis should be put on whether or not it could be homework, but rather on the quality of the question itself.

Comment: Note: I do not consider an introduction like "I have to solve this problem. Can anyone help? Pls" to be *effort shown*. A high-quality answer will, in addition to others, answer the question *what have you tried?*

Comment: I think it should be possible to hide/ignore closed questions. And maybe even question that are downvoted (with negative score for example). That would make this a better solution to the problem.

Comment: @Kasper, that could be detrimental in the following case: new user posts "low quality" question, which is immediately closed. Standard boilerplate comment is copy-pasted, and the user *makes appropriate changes to bring the question up to quality standards*. At this point, the question should be reopened. It would be harder for passersby to act on this if the question were invisible.

Comment: Another concern, related to your second one, is that the increasing volume of questions (irrespective of quality) decreases the amount of attention/views each question gets. This means both that (1) the question-asker of a good/interesting question gets fewer potential answerers to look at it, and that (2) even a good answer gets fewer people to see/appreciate/upvote/correct/dispute it, so giving answers is slightly less satisfying. (This might be slightly counterbalanced by an increase in the number of active users, but I don't think that's happening to a sufficient extent.)

Comment: This is a significant issue. I have found this site to be significantly less interesting than it used to be. The number of very low quality questions is a real turn-off.

Comment: What about making levels for MathSE? I mean, M1 including elementary and pre-... questions and M2 including some higher and so on.

Comment: For me, Qiaochu's remark:".. will drive away..." surely fits well. I feel a bit as in the famous "broken window" situations. Still I'm going to ask and answer, but my enthusiasm decreases much more than it would happen by the (well familiar) experience of getting-used-to-something and sometimes I've to keep myself to not to submit destructive answers/comments - which is something I never experienced in my 13-years usenet-interaction. Because I like a high politeness standard(?correct word) in receiving but also in exposing myself to others (... a prerequisite in ...

Comment: (... a prerequisite in a constructive, creative, friendly and humorous setting) I'm reducing my involvemet a lot here. Let it only be that simple fact, that you won't see any answer longer than a couple of hours on the first page of 50 questions. It's not the software, which helps to organize the reading through a growing load of sand in such a desert of material to find and organize your interesting threads. But that's just, for what software was invented: to organize loads of data to allow an focused and easy access. It seems to me intentionally that there is no discussion of improvement.

Answer (score 25):

We might start by asking:

> How do we measure the quality of questions?

To me, it's the presence (or absence) of motivation and effort.

Using this metric, I frequently vote - up and down - on questions. 
For similar underlying philosophical reasons, I also frequently upvote **answers** to these questions that are "hints" and downvote those that are "spoonfeeding".

I also vote to close a lot of questions.

---

What else can we do? Most of us can only vote: up, down, close. I have waited for a few years for a "consolidated policy" to come together, and none has. Everyone is in disagreement!

So my solution is personal; I vote a lot. It's the only meaningful expression of my puny political voice on this site, and I encourage everyone else to do the same.

Comment: I'm fairly new on here, but this is a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

I think the best way to reduce the number of low-quality questions is to stop answering them.  Unfortunately, many attract answers because they are relatively easy.  As a solution, closing them has a couple of problems: it takes a while, so that the question often has answers before it's closed (and so a drive-by asker doesn't care), and it seems decidedly unfriendly to new users who just don't know what's expected.

To address these, I have a proposal for a new software feature: putting questions "on hold."

It should be relatively easy for any established user (2000 rep?) to put a question on hold; it must be accompanied by a comment explaining how the question needs to be improved.

While the question is on hold, it cannot be answered, and does not show up on the lists of recent questions. (Possibly, any existing answers are hidden as well?)

The question is taken off hold automatically whenever it's edited.

---

The idea is this: someone posts a typical homework-type question ("Prove that the identity map on a topological space is continuous.")  An established user reading it can quickly add a comment ("Please expand on what you know about this problem and where you get stuck") and put it on hold. Then the asker can't get an answer until they attempt to improve their question. If they edit it, the assumption is that they made an honest effort at improvement.  If it's found that it's still low-quality, it can be put on hold again, or if no effort is being made, the question will be closed in the normal way.

It should have friendlier connotations ("Your question is worthwhile, but here's some things we want you to do before we look at it") than closure does.

Comment: I think this is absolutely the best solution.  +1 for (It should have friendlier connotations ("Your question is worthwhile, but here's some things we want you to do before we look at it") than closure does.)

Comment: I really don't think this solves anything.  Since taking a question off hold required virtually no effort, it would seem to have no value as a mechanism to enforce quality.  And once the holding-game has been gamed, we're back at square one and voting to close.  Should closures come in concert with comments explaining the situation?  Yes, I agree.  But beyond this courtesy I don't think we should worry ourselves too much about whether some user who just posted »prove Q is not finitely generated« thinks we're being unfair/unkind.

Comment: +1: This is definitely a problem. Some other causes are people wanting to show off, or to one-up other, more appropriate answers.

Comment: Besides being rather pointless, this is yet another attempt to limit other users’ ability to answer questions.

Comment: @Brian: It is a *good thing* to limit other users' ability to answer questions, so long as we maximize the limitation on the answers we don't want, and minimize the limitation on the answers we do want.

Comment: @Brian: And it is hard to be sympathetic to a desire to allow people to answers questions that the site doesn't actually want to be here.

Comment: @Hurkyl: No, it is not a good thing. // The site has no desires at all: it’s users do, and these desires do not always coincide. The difference between yours and mine in this instance is that yours would limit my freedom to engage in the primary function of this site — answering questions — while mine does not limit your freedom to do so.

Comment: Of course your desires limit my freedom to answer questions. If I can't find a question I want to answer because it's lost in the sea of junk, then I can't answer it. If the question I want to answer isn't asked because the author avoided MSE due to having a reputation as a junk heap, then I can't answer it. If nobody reads my answer because people use MSE as a paper mill and only look at canned solutions, then I might as well haven't answered it. If my sense of academic integrity forces me to leave MSE, I can't answer any questions.

Comment: The site is its users. If the site doesn't want a question here or an answer here, that means something resembling plurality consensus among users has decided they don't want it here. Are you seriously defending the presence of questions and answers **you** don't want? (you didn't seem to have any hesitation in another thread with limiting people's freedoms to ask and answer Harry Potter questions at MSE) If you are simply arguing a difference in desire, then the phrase `no it's not a good thing` is **extremely** misleading.

Comment: How do you divine the desires of "the site"?  In Qiaochu's recent question there are 23 +votes on a comment saying that even the least-obtrusive deviation from the status quo "would damage the site but anything is better than a closing policy" ; 26 votes for "your implication that cut-paste questions involve cheating is false and offensive"; and under another question, 13 for "ban proposals that ban valid mathematical questions".  There is *substantial* fragmentation of opinion on *many* aspects of these matters. E.g., the pro-closing people do not agree on HW vs CPHQ vs (let us pray) CPQ.

Comment: If you can't find questions you want to answer, and CPQ that would be deleted is on the order (by your estimate) of maybe 5 to 20 percent, how does that help you finally?  Why the *agitas* about homework when under your most optimistic predictions, the efficiency gained in selecting material you like is fairly light, and less (in my opinion) than what would be gained by improvements on the titles, tags and references front.  There is not a peep about those on meta from the people who seriously suggest that 75 percent of questions can be drowned in a sea of the 10 percent. @Hurkyl

Comment: @zyx: How do I divine the desires of "the site"? Simple: I look at meta, and actions people actually take on the main site.

Comment: @zyx: I have no "agitas" about homework. Let me know when you decide to stop pretending that the people who are pushing for a small step towards a reasonable policy on low quality questions are anti-homework, let me know.

Comment: Is it my imagination that you have posted a very large  barrage of comments/answers/proposals on meta about the supposed scourge of "low quality questions" and homework (exam, etc) "cheating", and nothing about the likely more effective avenues involving titles, tags and other selectable attributes?  I have not said or "pretended" that you or the pro-closing faction as a whole oppose the presence of homework on the site, or the answering of homework (although some of them do oppose all of it).  This was spelled out to you quite explicitly and maybe you/Asaf can stop that shtick. @Hurkyl

Comment: The question was how you arrived at a single, unitary thing declared as what "the site wants" when all that looking at the meta or main would show a very fragmented set of user preferences.  If you happen to be the previously undeclared spokesman for the thousands of MSE users, my bad, just say so and we can move on.  Otherwise, there is still some explaining to do.  @Hurkyl

Comment: As suggested earlier, maybe you could nominate the abbreviated term you prefer for the approximate set of positions that you and similarly inclined meta commenters espouse.  Anti-CPHQ?  Pro-closing?  I don't care what it is, but there is very obviously a left and right wing on all of these matters and a need to refer to it without spelling everything out each time or being dragged into inane repetitions of the question whether writing "anti-homework" is the proper shorthand phrase. @Hurkyl

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Many of us come to MSE to find interesting mathematical questions. Questions are more interesting if they have some context and motivation so that we know why to care about them. It's better yet if they have a story: How they came up, what the asker thought about, how they got stuck. Then you're part of the story, and overcome the barriers or provide a twist ending. If we just want to find exercises from a problem set, most of us have plenty on our bookshelves. <cont>

Comment: You would say that we can just ignore those questions we don't find interesting. Unfortunately that doesn't work, because the site is flooded with hundreds of such questions a day, and it becomes impossible to separate the wheat from the chaff. I am new around here, but I've been disappointed to have answers I worked hard on ignored, getting no upvotes. I see many decent questions and good answers similarly ignored. I believe that is because there are too many questions for people to read them all, so good things are lost in the flux. <cont>

Comment: It is very discouraging to get no acknowledgment for one's work. I believe that if this continues unchecked, MSE will stop attracting new contributors, and eventually decay into something like answers.yahoo.com.

Comment: @Kundor, the premise of a site like SE is that with more users comes more questions but also more "collaborative filtering" : up/down/close votes on questions, editing of titles, attachment of useful tags.  If this is not working (either in fact or in the opinion of some users), the first thing to do is exhaust the options that maintain the freedom of users on the site, especially answerers, and restrict it only as a last resort.  I believe that ease of select interesting questions comes from pushing good material to the top, not deciding for others what constitutes the deletable sludge.

Comment: @zyx: It is definitely not working. I could proffer many examples of fine questions with no votes (besides mine.) [Here's one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365155/showing-that-no-hamilton-circuit-exists). It might not be stellar, but it's a real question.  The user (a new guy) got no recognition whatsoever. Besides my vote, there was _nothing_ to say "Hey, you're welcome here, well asked." I think this is unacceptable.

Comment: @zyx Perhaps the issue is that MSE isn't getting more _users_, who would contribute to "filtering," but more "drive-by askers."

Comment: Maybe: there was some data on MSE vs physics and other sites in one of the first of the ongoing wave of "ban this!" questions.  I looked at users per question and answers per user and what you say is plausible.  But it is impossible for a site to grow without that happening, or to enforce a return to the bucolic early days with a high density of committed users and MO experts, low traffic to read everything easily, and relatively non-diverse base of core users.  Deleting less than 20 percent of questions won't help you when the userbase doubles in 10 more months, but titles tags etc will.

Comment: In essence, you can't get around the fact that the early users are a more qualified group, many of whom were Mathoverflow active users playing with a new toy, who got the picture after a while and left.  There is a limited supply of early adopters of discussion technology, as MathGem said a large number of the high rep users are familiar faces from every previous math site.  The new users will not be professors and hardcore online math-heads, but come more from the unlimited supply of students and nonexperts and non-English speakers. Undoing the diversification by rules is an impossible dream.

Comment: @zyx It is definitely worh thinking about which changes we can control and which changes we can't control. But I think your timeline is not completely accurate. Sometimes, highly qualified users become active on MSE and then get discouragd and leave.

Comment: @Kundor: I do not in general find that such information has any effect on how interesting I find a question. It may help me to provide a more useful answer, but for me the interest is inherent in the question. The interest may be mathematical, or it may be paedagogical, but it's in the question and not usually in the context. And I can find the interesting questions pretty quickly just by scanning the Questions page(s), even without filtering.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, and sometimes ultra qualified users appear and contribute actively.  I noticed some well known professors and a Putnam competition winner, among others. Unsubstantiated talk of reputational problems driving away MSE users, or deciding for people who left that they did so because of a lack of bans on homework/cutpaste/lowquality/cheating/(whatever), is known as *FUD* ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt ), i.e., deliberately or by implication trying to scare people into supporting a ban for reasons that may be imaginary.

Comment: @zyx Who is doing that?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, have you not noticed a number of proponents, such as Asaf, or Hurkyl above ("If the question I want to answer isn't asked because the author avoided MSE due to having a reputation as a junk heap, then I can't answer it ") talking a lot about MSE reputation of homework/junk/cheating/whatev scaring away competent contributors?  And saying that they and people like them will leave the site if this cheating or whatnot is supposedly rampant on MSE ("If my sense of academic integrity forces me to leave MSE, I can't answer any questions")?  Didn't we discuss search engine issues?

Comment: Or Will Jagy talking about an active Mathoverflow user leaving because of homework solutions/cheating on MSE, when in fact (according to a later message from that user, clarifying) that person left because of a dislike for opinion diversity *about* homework solutions on the MSE meta?  If you don't see this kind of argument being made constantly in the meta comments maybe we are reading very different sites.  The FUD argument is that if we don't act Right Now to stop a Big Problem, reputational problems will drive away the experts who can retire to the safe bosom of sites with Integrity.

Comment: @zyx I'm not sure these gentlemen make unsubstantiated claims. There are people like Mark Sapir who outright state the would never visit MSE because of its treatment of homework. Asaf and Hurkyl are moderates. Hurkyl's response to Brian pointed to potential effects of laissez faire policy that might hinder him from answering questions. And please stop relating this stuff to grand politics. Sometimes, I think you describe everyone who disagree with you as the MSE equivalent of Dick Cheney.

Comment: Sorry, what grand politics or Cheney-ization are you talking about, specifically (quotation, please)? I'm saying that these people and others have said X, over and over, on the meta.  To support X it is almost irrelevant to name individuals like Sapir, because dozens of other equally qualified individuals "voted with their feet" and do participate.  I can name other experts who refuse to participate in controlled or moderated forums.  You can tell any story you like about this issue, which is the problem: nobody knows, and the imagined or imaginary problems are used to imply disaster.

Comment: @zyx You called my general behavior on meta authoritarian, because I mentioned names of people who have publicly posted something under their name. You call this a right/left divide here. Your use of terms like 'Jihad', 'crusade', etc. Btw: There is adifference between not having evidence and you not being convinced by the evidence. Reading stuff like [this](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1348/if-we-were-more-responsible/) helps to put things in perspective.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, I think I deleted the authoritarian comment after some remark by you, and in any case, please accept my apologies.   There is a left/right divide, and I invited Hurkyl (or you, if you like) to state his preferred term so as to avoid arguments over words.  The same people arguing against cheating on homework are arguing to close take-home exams are arguing against cut-paste questions are arguing against low-quality are arguing to close low-effort are justifying individual question closures (etc).  And the same for the other "side", my position, Brian's, MathGem's are alike.

Comment: Correcting the record, once again: I never used the word "crusade", that one came from Didier Piau (did you upvote him for it?).  I have never used a term like jihad, crusade or holy war to describe anyone's arguments for one policy or another on MSE.  I used the word jihad for *vicious, unrelenting, gratuitous user on user attacks*, a war-without-end by one senior user on another.  Please stop misrepresenting that (and the same request x10 to Hurkyl, Asaf and a few others). @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: @Michael: Hurkyl is by no stretch of the imagination a moderate, either in his position or, even more obviously, in his language.

Comment: @Brian: Hurkyl I consider an odd combination of very smart (great writer!), well intentioned (best interests of MSE at heart!), and utterly propagandistic poster who will repeatedly disregard or avoid what others write if it makes for better rhetoric.

Comment: @zyx I'm not sure it is that clear. Qiaochu Yuan seems to have real issues with homework. Asaf and Hurkyl seem to care mostly about quality and copy-paste. I'm pretty sure you count me in the described group, and I don't care much about homework. Things like "honor codes" are completely absurd to me. The fundamental issue is that people disagree on what and how strictly rules should be enforced. I think one can discuss these issues in a more detached way. I'm perfectly aware that my own writngs often do not live up to the highest standard.

Comment: @Brian I think there is little correlation in ones views on MSE policies and the language chosen. In particular, I think you are probable the most soft-spoken member of your camp.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, I did not consider you one of the group, since your expressed opinion in your answer to one of these questions was moderate.  My unrelated impression is that you persistently contest many things I say in comments for what often are ultimately reasons of writing style or "online personality" but are  ostensibly expressed as disagreements over content.  I don't necessarily enjoy that, but I don't hate it either.

Comment: @Michael: I’m flattered but also surprised: I think of zyx as being more soft-spoken than I, which is one reason I’ve been happy to let him carry more than his fair share of the load! (For what it’s worth, I consider you a reasonable moderate.)

Comment: Peace everyone. Have to leave.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, by the way, Qiaochu and Hurkyl positions on homework are essentially the same.  They both emphasize cheating as the real issue, and rightly so: it would be strange to try hard to stop material they don't consider questionable.  The difference is that Hurkyl seems to recognize that there is more room for a united front on the desired result (closing/deletion of certain questions) when arguments are formulated amorally in terms of question volume, cut-paste, and other practical matters. Qiaochu is less compromising and says every time that he wants it all gone.

Comment: @Kundor: Concerning your example of a fine question with no vote but yours: it now has another. With my focus on answering questions I sometimes simply forget to vote, as I did on that one.

Comment: @zyx: My level of emphasis on cheating is purely a function of engaging people who, forgive the adjective, are making some really silly arguments pushing an anti-anti-cheating view that furthermore touches on one of my pet peeves: platitudes (which are "thought stopping", to toss out a phrase you like). While I could write reasonable arguments resembling many of the ones I find silly, doing so would be a straw man as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I’ve not seen anyone make any such arguments. I *have* seen you misrepresent reasonable arguments.

Comment: @Hurkyl, it's hard to make head or tail of what you wrote, but instead of generously repairing our supposedly faulty arguments with straw maybe it's not too much trouble to say what ethical problem you think is present in the cut-paste-copy cheating scenario (CPQ, complete answer).  My view is that the locus of un-ethicalness is in the instructors and institutions assigning required homework, that this will come to be the standard opinion in future, and that present discussions of how to prevent disruption of the sacred academic integrity are protecting an unstable and immoral status quo.

Comment: @zyx: You say it is impossible to return to the bucolic days when MSE had a higher ratio of committed users, which may be true. But my proposal is an attempt at this, by giving "drive-by askers" incentive to put more effort into their questions. This will lead to them learning the community norms, developing some judgment about what's good here, and with luck "suck them in" so that they become contributors, too.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: To belatedly address your actual objection, I think the limit on freedom of answering is not too great, since an answerer is free to edit the question, addressing whatever caused the question to be put on hold, and then answer it.

Comment: @Kundor: Absolutely not: I consider it completely inappropriate for anyone to make substantive changes in someone else’s question. Converting links to embedded images or images to text or $\LaTeX$ is fine, as is correcting truly obvious typos, but I don’t consider anything beyond that acceptable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I disagree. SE is meant to collect archival quality questions, which will be useful for searchers through the centuries to come. We should ensure that questions are clear and understandable so that others with the same question can find it. We should include motivation so that browsers know why they might care. Everything is primarily intended for posterity, and only secondarily for the benefit of the asker.

Comment: @Kundor: Speaking as a potential browser, I consider motivation irrelevant: either I find a question interesting, or I don’t, and no amount of someone else’s motivation is likely to change that. And as I’ve said before, my first concern is to help the person asking the question; **then** I may do something extra for posterity. (And as long as Google remains the best way to search MSE, good answers will serve just as well as artificially prettied-up questions to make it possible to find useful material.)

Comment: @zyx: `what ethical problem ... cut-paste-copy cheating scenario (CPQ, complete answer)`. The literal question you ask is trivial, since ethical codes generally expressly forbid the the relevant activities (presenting others' work as your own, and providing your work to be used in such a fashion), and do not consider *willful* ignorance to be any defense of a violation. The more pragmatic view is that it is disruptive to (an ideal of) how society works, both by making it difficult to evaluate a person's ability, and by denying opportunities to those more deserving....

Comment: ... of course, I'm just an armchair philosopher restricted to a few hundred characters, so I can't really do the topic justice. But then, I imagine if you truly cared why people are opposed to cheating, you would have asked google rather than me....

Comment: And this fits into one of those game theory scenarios too (Prisoner's dilemma? Or is it one of the related ones?). Cheating is perceived to have an excellent good risk / reward ratio, and cheaters profit at the expense of others. This pressures others into cheating to keep up. This has been rationalized away by saying that the cheater isn't learning, but I believe that has been rather soundly debunked. The real damage, I think, isn't the freshman who drops out his third year because he didn't learn anything: it's the mediocre student who successfully masquerades as an excellent one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It seems difficult for any mathematical question to be interesting without motivation. I could define a K-space to be a 3-manifold with a free action by a finite group of order $p^2 q^3 r^4 s^5$ where $p,q,r,s$ are distinct primes, and ask for a parametrization of any infinite families of such spaces. Wouldn't you want to know _why_? It seems obvious to me that this could be a very interesting problem, if there were some reason to care, and otherwise it's not. Probably, you just already know what motivates the problems you find interesting. But that doesn't mean everyone does.

Comment: @Hurkyl, ethical codes tend not to say anything about "presenting others' work as your own" when there is no authorship or intellectual property at stake, and they also tend not to say anything about "disruptions of the way that a society works" without an analysis of the moral health of the social practices being disrupted. MSE assistants to the cut-paste posters are close to the moral situation of people who help citizens of China circumvent internet censorship: some violation of local rules (and thus lying or other ills) is involved, but the rules are the only real problem.

Comment: @Kundor, for the typical "low effort posting", it is an exercise that is known to have a solution, and used in a book or class or contest because of the belief that it might be instructive, challenging, interesting, beautiful, or otherwise worth solving.  This is sufficient motivation for many people on MSE to have a look and try it.  It does not have to be part of a story-book narrative demonstrating compelling intellectual interest for a broad section of (mathematically educated) humankind.  The latter is an ideal that is sometimes seen in questions, and usually not.

Comment: @Hurkyl, for all of the pragmatic concerns you listed, it is again the institutions (by evaluating their own students) and the instructors (by using required homework in the evaluation) that bear the overwhelming share of the fault.   Homework creates far more noise and corruption in student evaluations than cheating on homework, and the instructors have no legitimate reason to use it in the evaluation.  I'm referring here to assembly line homework (problem sets) that can make its way to MSE, not the writing assignments used in humanities classes, though those are also fraught with problems.

Comment: Here is one game theoretic observation. By awarding grades and other commodities based in part on homework, instructors create an incentive to cheat, but the means of cheating is not distributed equally among students. Wealthy students can hire an assistant to write the homework for them, and the more socially or academically connected students have access to people and resources that can help.  MSE answers reduce this inequity by lowering the cost of "cheating" closer to zero. What a clampdown on MSE-cheating would protect is *privileged* cheaters, not the mythical academic integrity. @Hurkyl

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, by the way, your example (Prof. Sapir) who avoids MSE because of homework answers also says that any mathematician who helps a student with a homework assignment should be fired (which is interesting considering that the university that pays his salary probably operates a math tutoring center), expresses other very unusual opinions on MathOverflow, has a recording on his web page singing to students that they are stupid, and generally seems like an extremely poor indicator of "average opinion".  Did you have some more typical cases in mind, or is this mostly hypothetical?

Comment: @zyx My imprssion is that the more hawkish fraction of MO is quite often in agreement with MS, even though he expresses his views in less diplomatic ways. Harry Gindi certainly tries t defame MSE on MO, and I wouldn't be surprised if some of it sticks. But I have of cours no definitive evidence of any kind.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, Harry is even more atypical than MS, has a history of being less diplomatic, and has possibly unique issues with MSE due to a one-year suspension, after which he never came back.  Yemon just clarified that his reason for leaving MSE was the way conversations went in the meta, not the homework answers or associated reputation issues.  I'm not saying that nobody has ever expressed distaste for solving homework on MSE (or MO itself, for that matter) but the idea that this makes a reputational problem seems unlikely, the problem is more that using MSE is viewed as wasting time.

Comment: @Kundor: It seems difficult *to you*; you will simply have to take my word for it that my interests work differently. Your example is in a field about which I know nothing, so obviously I’m not interested, with or without motivation. Whether I’d be interested in it if I knew something about it, however, is independent of the motivation for asking the question: either I find the question inherently interesting, or I don’t. It makes no difference to me whether it’s idle curiosity or part of a research program with connections to umpteen areas of mathematics.

Comment: @zyx: I suppose your characterization of Sapir's statements have the same level of accuracy as when you label me as being anti-homework?

Comment: @zyx: Why not set up a free contract killer service, so that the rich aren't advantaged in that respect either? And I suppose when someone hires contract killers, the only person who deserves any blame is the victim, because he set up a situation where another person wanted him dead?

Comment: @zyx: If you want to make MSE a paper mill to effect some form of civil disobedience (what's the right term when it's not directed at the government?), I suppose you're free to try, but I can't imagine you will get much support for such a crusade. It's interesting you try to distinguish essays from homework, because the *canonical term* for what you propose is derived from supplying essays ready to be handed in.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I have no desire for MSE to effectuate civil disobedience (which it cannot, since no laws are being broken, and anyway a lot of people might be puzzled by the idea that asking and answering math questions is harming anyone).  I only want MSE to be neutral or indifferent to whatever happens in academia, not anti-anything.  If the game theoretic effect is to push away from the status quo and toward a more ethically defensible equilibrium, while gaining the benefit of "disruptive tech", that's great, but I don't see a need to accelerate or retard that process or even pay attention to it.

Comment: @Hurkyl, it's been a while since I read the MO thread and Sapir's web site, but feel free to spell out any misrepresentations that you think exist and are important here.  Sapir is an extremist, however represented, and as Greinecker seemed to acknowledge after I mentioned it, not a reliable window onto some supposed iceberg of opinion according to which MSE is a morally degenerate "homework mill", and its users' careers harmed by their participation.  And to correct the record an Nth time, I don't say you are against homework. Name the shorthand you want for your position and I'll use it.

Comment: Did I notice the word *crusade* up there, and a comparison of homework assistance to *murder*?  I recall people displaying (or more likely, feigning) sensitivity about such things here lately...

Comment: @zyx: I did put thought into my word choice. Assuming noble intent, I think it's a fair description of your efforts to make MSE a place to fight against the injustice of equal access to cheating. If I don't assume noble intent, it sounds more like you're rationalizing to avoid feeling guilty about your feelings on cheating, and to dissuade others from taking action in opposition.

Comment: And yes, murder. I reject your argument that the correct response to inequality of access is to increase availability. Such an argument requires rationale that increased availability leads to making things better. Murder rather plainly demonstrates that sometimes, the correct response is exactly the opposite. The only rationale I see in your argument that increasing availability of cheating is the correct response is the civil disobedience one. (and, incidentally, you do seem to be paying a lot of attention to the topic)

Comment: @Hurkyl, I'm not making any argument that availability should be increased to solve a problem of inequality of access.  The problem is the corruption in the present academic system, and MSE certainly disrupts some of that. I simply pointed out as an aside that the policy *you* advocate is really one of protecting privileged cheaters and not defending any integrity (of which there is little) in the system.

Comment: @Hurkyl, since you say you oppose "do my homework for me" communiques (and the more truthful paraphrase would have been the milder "help do my possible-homework for me, if you like"), how can you defend the evidently much more offensive command from the instructors, "do this homework by 9am next Wednesday, or else"?

Comment: @zyx: It's bewildering that the notion of a due date is coming under attack. But it's also off topic (unless you're going to take that 'civil disobedience'-esque stance you didn't want to).

Comment: @zyx: Of course, I also find it bewildering that you seem to describe your views as one that inhibits corruption even as you champion MSE's role in its spread.

Comment: @Hurkyl, the explicit threat, not the due date, is the main thing making instructors' assignments significantly more offensive than anything that might bother you about the cut-paste-command postings in MSE.  I can see why you would want to avoid any discussion of that, as there is no apparent defense of the practice, nor is there any use for it pedagogically.

Comment: @zyx Are you seriously claiming that there is no good reason to put a deadline on homework assignments?

Comment: Seriously people, stop comparing m.SE policies to murder!  What does it add to anything?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, no. I am claiming that there is no good reason for the threat (and the command that it enforces) associated with homework that is used for evaluation.  If the threat is removed by separating homework from evaluation of students, that would reduce the scope of what is governed by deadlines, but there is nothing wrong (that I can see) with deadlines as such.  An instructor might refuse to check the voluntarily submitted, ungraded homework from chapter 3 when the lectures have reached chapter 10, or after the class is over, and that is completely reasonable.

Comment: @NoahSnyder, this is the first time m.SE policies have been compared to murder.  Where Hurkyl writes "crusade" above, that is inconsistent with his earlier complaint about others' use of the term, but it is not an assertion that I am out to destroy non-Christian heathens.  And when people use terms like jihad, holy war, bolshie, fascist or feminazi in casual conversation, they are not implying any tendency toward murder or an affiliation with the political programs associated with the murders.  If you don't want such terms used that is understandable, but they are not charges of murder.

Comment: @Kundor Your problem about three manifolds looks like it could be "intrinsically interesting" if it has non-trivial solutions.

Comment: *"It's interesting you try to distinguish essays from homework"*.   I only distinguish them as being worse.  Required essays share the same general ethical and pedagogical troubles as required problem sets, but I did not want to get into a digression on methods of evaluation in non-technical subjects.  Who should evaluate is the same in both cases: somebody other than the instructor or the institution collecting tuition fees.  The observation that status quo involves massive conflicts of interest and distorts evaluation is starting to become mainstream (someone here cited a TED talk!). @Hurkyl

Comment: @zyx: Do recall that *you* were the one complaining about such terms being used; I just highlighted the hypocrisy.

Comment: @Hurkyl, no, I don't recall, (partly because you don't make clear which comment you are responding to) but a quotation or link would suffice to remind me, or anyone else interested in whether you are inventing things. What terminological complaint, and what hypocrisy do you claim to have revealed in relation to that?  Also, if your meta.MSE activity is to volunteer to detect hypocrisy, bad ethics, cognitive failures and unstated premises, aren't all those totally off topic?

Comment: @zyx: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/discussion-what-should-we-do-about-the-increasing-number-of-questions/9207?noredirect=1#comment32904_9193

Comment: Finally a link!  It contains a list of some demagogical tactics that you used many times. Since you are claiming hypocrisy, what you need now is a second link with equivalent rhetoric making negative assertions about the ethical qualities of individual pro-closing posters (like "questionable" and "cheating" that you used to slime Prof. Scott), or defining their views and MSE use as morally alien (*ibid*), or calling their use of the meta to argue those views a "crusade", or using an emotionalized term like *police state* for the pro-closing counterpart to an MSE "answer service". @Hurkyl

Answer (score 7):

I think that being able to filter the question which are typically found as an exercise in a mathematical book, could solve part of the problem here. Some people would say that those question should be tagged as homework, but according to the topic, this is not true: [What is a homework question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5037/what-is-a-homework-question)

> It's homework if
>
> 1. You're a student, and
> 2. Your teacher told you to do it, and
> 3. You're expected to do it on your own, or report any help you got on it.

And according to this topic: [Proper use of the (homework) tag redux](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/proper-use-of-the-homework-tag-redux)

> I and many other users consider it inappropriate to tag another user's
>   question as homework unless they have explicitly said it is homework.

Therefore, the questions tagged as homework are a (proper) subset of the questions typically found as an exercise in mathematical book. I think there are many reason to add a new tag, for example called "book-exercise" to cover this complete set of questions.

For example. it is considered inappropriate to tag another user's question as homework, but I don't think it would be inappropiate to tag another user's question as an book exercise. I think such a new tag would do a much better job in filtering these kind of questions.

Comment: Not all the questions copied verbatim from book exercises are bad and in fact there are some really interesting. +1 I like your idea, but instead of add a new tag I think it's better to add in somewhere (FAQ or meta), that questions which are from books must indicate the book they come from. For example a header: "This is question xx on page yyy from book _Some Book_ by Some Author". That way, knowing which the book is, you can infer some more things, and if you woul add information to a question to indicate that it come from a book, why not spend a bit more to say from which book?

Comment: There’s often room for argument as to whether something qualifies, but on the whole I think that this would help those whose primary goal is better filtering.

Comment: @leo: Not all ‘book questions’ actually come from specific books.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was referring to the questions copied exactly as they are in the book. I thought that the whole answer was about this. You're right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Exactly, I think better fitlering is the most easy solution as it comes to problem of increasing number of question. I do think this is a problem as question get a shorter and shorter attention span. Those book-exercise questions have the luck of getting often more then one answer. Therefore they are likely to get much more views, then many of those more advanced questions. I think some of those questions will be already at page 2 within 20 min, quite sad IMO.

Answer (score 6):

This suggestion involves changes in the SE platform, so I am far from holding my breath.

I find it surprising that a site of this level of sophistication, and which clearly has plenty of employees tinkering with the platform on a nearly constant basis, does not provide *viewing options* for users.  In particular:

$\bullet$ The "ignored" tags currently work in a rather anemic way: questions with these tags still appear on the page, only in very light-face text.  This succeeds in creating some tendency for the eye to slide past them (but probably to a variable degree depending on the user) but does not increase the rate at which users can see desirable questions.  I only ignore a few tags, but I would imagine that for users who ignore a large number of tags, each page would be a sea of light-face questions populated by little islands of actual questions.  Why not allow, as an option, ignored tags to truly be ignored?

$\bullet$ Dually it would be nice if there were an option to only see questions with favorited tags.

Comment: It is possible to completely hide tags by checking a box in one's preferences. Someone has also made some scripts to only display favorites or to not hide favorite tags when they are used together with ignored ones. I will find a link when I am not on a tablet.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, Were you thinking of [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8561/5531)?

Comment: Hmm, not only did I not know about this, I didn't even know there *were* preferences.  That's what I was asking for in my answer above.  Armed with this knowledge I was able to find and click on something tiny on my user page.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AntonioVargas that plus the answer linked in the last comment to the answer you link.

Comment: Although there is no built-in option to see *only* favorite tags, there is an option to see *more* questions with favorite tags, by opening the undocumented tab [interesting](http://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=interesting).  (See also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9249/75064)).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was not aware of the hide ignored tags feature. Plenty thanks.

Comment: I just found that there **is** a way to see only questions with favorited tags: bookmarking [favorite tags filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/89000/favorite-tags) does the trick. One does not need to login to stackexchange.com itself; being logged in to Math.SE appears to be enough for the filter to work. The downside is that the results are displayed with default theme, rather than with Math.SE theme, and without MathJax processing.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, improving the quality should help to reduce the quantity. So how about adding a checklist on the page where you ask questions? You have to manually tick each point on the checklist in order to be able to post a question.

The checklist could include the sorts of things that new users tend to fail to do. "Have you checked to see if your question has been asked before?", "If this is a homework question, have you tagged it as such?", "Have you included information on your own attempt at answering your question?", etc.

The checklist requirement could then be removed at a certain number of points, so that regular users aren't stuck with having to do it manually every time. But it should help to filter out people who don't put any effort at all into the questions.

Comment: My understanding is that SE will only allow such things to happen if they happen across all of the SE sites (they value the experience being relatively uniform across the network), and this kind of policy would kill smaller sites. I think all we can really do is change our standards for voting and closing.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to think about is what has happened to MathOverflow over this period - there is a stricter discipline there now with a very clear focus on research level.

The first of the FAQ says

> Mathematics - Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields.

It depends what is meant by the "quality of questions" - but I would suggest that if "at any level" is retained, that would include people without the mathematical knowledge or maturity to pose a perfect question in the first place.

So part of the issue is whether the level of demand on this site is such that it could usefully be split into a higher level and a lower level so that there would be three levels rather than the current two. The challenge of doing this would be to find moderators and regular answerers for the lower level site - while I note a number of regulars on here seem to enjoy the coaching aspect of making comments and framing good answers, they might not be attracted to a pool of "lower quality" material.

I would suggest that one of the of the reasons that MathOverflow is successful in quality control is that this site provides a good alternative place for people to go to get their questions answered.

In short, tighter moderation and quality control effectively adjusts the supply of answers. The other side of the question would be what to do with the demand which is so evident in the current volume of questions.

As an aside - Personally I am busier on other things, so less engaged here than I was - but also it is harder to find questions which are interesting to me.

Comment: One of the things that I like about MSE is that I can go from coaching someone through a very elementary combinatorics problem to helping someone fill in the gaps in an argument in a research paper in topology. I like the variety.

Comment: I don't see this problem. If you cannot coherently formulate a question, the math level may be too high relative to the poster, but there are still thing the poster could ask about. If someone has problems adding three and four apples but knows how to solve the equivalent problem for oranges, there is enough to work with.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You were one of the people I was thinking about ...

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I don't have a personal problem with this. But it does seem to lie behind some of the dissatisfaction about so-called question quality. High school students might, for example, be asking questions about real numbers in the absence of any clear understanding of a rigorous definition - let alone the issues involved in a good definition of the reals. I wanted to point out that this might be the case, rather than to suggest that it is necessarily wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, my reply to

> What should we do with the questions?

is:

> Answer them.

I don't think the number of questions here is too overwhelming. If you are horrified by what we observe here, check out Stack Overflow, where new questions might drop down to page two unnoticed between page refreshes ...
We are here still in the lucky situation that hardly any question manages to stay unanswered (admittedly, there's but about a dozen of tumbleweed badges "awarded" each day)

A nice amount of questions also helps make sure that the *range* of topics remains broad enough to cover all levels (as intended)

Comment: And even if my definition of *interesting* were quite a bit narrower than it is, I could still honestly say that I find lots of interesting questions. Of course you find some of them first ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one would see the growing volume of questions as a sign of success.  I do not perceive a decline in the overall quality of questions and discussions on the forum.  I think this site is doing a great job of fulfilling its objectives.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that this site is open to everyone, I strongly doubt if there is an age limit (correct me if I am wrong). From  grade school math to  high school math to college math to post graduate studies and research works. This difference in level/difficulty can upset some people who are looking to involve only in a certain difficulty. If we take some statistics and find out that the community has a higher percentage of high school students for example, these students will (most probably) only be able to answer and post questions at high school level thus leading to a vast amount of questions in high school level which may render the community low in quality to some people, most probably of higher level.

Looking at the period of the year where the site receives higher traffic, I couldn't get any stats here from http://data.stackexchange.com/ but using a simple logic; if this site has a higher percentage of college students, one will observe that the traffic of their activities will depend on the situation of schools around the world. When school resumes, there will be low activity. Close to mid terms, traffic reduces and close to finals, the traffic explodes.

I am not saying that the only thing people come to MSE to do is school work but if this site has 60% high school + college students, then pick an average student from high school or college and ask him why he would be interested in a site like MSE. The first thing his mind would go to is probably homework or classwork or study for exam. in this situation, we all know how wild the media is these days, if one student finds out a trick on how to get his homework done here *lazily*, he will most definitely share this trink with his other friends and then the trend will go on and the percentage increases and *quality* reduces.

Moving up to a higher level with post graduate, research works and professors. in this situation, I would compare MSE with SO and SuperUser SE. These two sites involve a large percentage of members that have almost constant interaction with the subject of the community everyday of their lives. Take for example in the summer one would find less of high school and college students here on MSE because well, it's summer and everyone should be on break. But a user in SO or SuperUser didn't stop using his gadget and probably didn't stop coding and then wouldn't need an homework to encounter a problem or situation that will bring him to the club. The same goes to post graduates and researchers and professors here on MSE, Maths is no longer a school subject to them, it's now their *life* so their traffic on the site won't vary much from time to time. To some people Math is work, to some a burden, to some fun, to some it is their life and each and everyone of us must go through Maths in life to have a formal education. In this situation the question is; What percentage of the community do they hold?

If the percentage is high like on MO then it is good for everyone and most people will agree on the quality of the community. But if the percentage is low in comparison with school and college students then there *may* be a problem. there may be a problem because members in this higher level are the *voices* and *leaders* of the community and the community is seen through their eyes so if the community is filled with high school and college students who ask questions that is way lower than their level, they *may* tend to believe that the community has a low quality and this belief can spread.

In summary, it is difficult to find a solution that will make this community interesting for anyone as the number of users explodes without chasing away some users. One solution may be to split the site into various branches of Mathematics but then Mathematics wouldn't have a meaning. Another solution may be to enforce a tag that denotes the level/difficulty of the question as presumed by the asker. Of course these level must follow a well defined norm and moderators and editors will be able to correct a wrongly placed question. Just because the difficulty level of a question is *easy* shouldn't necessarily mean the answerer can't upgrade the level of his answer but must do so after having successfully answered the asker's question to his level of understanding. In this way, users who feel some questions are low in quality because of their difficulty can easily filter them out.

Comment: SE has an age limit; children under 13 (or is it 13 and under?) are not allowed (for liability reasons IIRC).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought as much. I just searched through the terms and it says $<13$.

Comment: At least for me, the coexistence of different branches of math and the great variety in difficulty of questions is precisely what makes this site interesting. It is refreshing to alternate  between tricky questions in area A (about which I know something) and basic questions in area B (about which I know very little). If the site were to be divided at all, I'd rather see it split *by purpose*, as reddit: they have  `/r/learnmath` and `/r/cheatatmathhomework`. The former bans "Do this for me" posts; the latter takes everything.

Answer (score -13):

> math.SE is experiencing a much bigger load of questions than it used to

I think the solution is specialisation. In particular, just as usenet used to have separate groups for statistics, geometry, algebra etc ... I think the general math.stackexchange.com branch is far too general, that it is handling vastly too many postings, and that it should be subdivided into more specialised groups such as:

```
stats.stackexchange.com   (which already exists)
topology.stackexchange.com
algebra.stackechange.com
numbertheory.stackexchange.com
...
```

The use of tags for things like probability and random variables and pdf etc etc etc ... does not alter the fact that these subjects belong in their own separate group.